# Getting error while installing Angular cli to create Angular2 project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am trying to create the first Angular2 project, and did some installation process which are given below.

```
npm install -g angular-cli

ng new my-new-app
```

After running above command I am getting the following error.

```
2study/newapp/node_modules/.staging/selenium-webdriver-4a4eda8a/lib/test'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/opt/lampp/htdocs/angular2study/newapp/node_modules/.staging/selenium-webdriver-4a4eda8a/lib/test'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/opt/lampp/htdocs/angular2study/newapp/node_modules/.staging/selenium-webdriver-4a4eda8a/lib/test'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/opt/lampp/htdocs/angular2study/newapp/node_modules/.staging/selenium-webdriver-4a4eda8a/lib/test'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/opt/lampp/htdocs/angular2study/newapp/node_modules/.staging/selenium-webdriver-4a4eda8a/lib/test'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/opt/lampp/htdocs/angular2study/newapp/node_modules/.staging/selenium-webdriver-4a4eda8a/lib/firefox'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/opt/lampp/htdocs/angular2study/newapp/node_modules/.staging/selenium-webdriver-4a4eda8a/lib/firefox'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/opt/lampp/htdocs/angular2study/newapp/node_modules/.staging/selenium-webdriver-4a4eda8a/lib/firefox'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/opt/lampp/htdocs/angular2study/newapp/node_modules/.staging/selenium-webdriver-4a4eda8a/lib/firefox'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/subrajyoti/.npm/_logs/2018-01-13T06_57_18_354Z-debug.log

Package install failed, see above.
```

I need to fix this error.

Comment: npm install selenium-webdriver

Comment: @ArefZamani : Yes, error gone . Thank you. but when when I am typing ng serve its showing `ng-serve: command not found`.

Comment: you must use ng serve instead of ng-serve

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to install selenium-webdriver run the following command

```
npm install selenium-webdriver --save
```

Comment: did the answer help ?

Answer (score 0):

try  `npm install selenium-webdriver`
and then use

```
ng serve
```

Comment: I run your command and run `ng serve` and its showing `ng-serve: command not found`.

Comment: try : npm install npm@latest -g

Comment: you must first enter  cd my-new-app then enter ng serve